# Are the spark-examples no longer published to the maven repository?

Tags: apache-spark

The latest spark-examples I can find in mvnrepo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-examples_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am specifically looking for spark-examples for scala 2.11 on spark 1.2.0/1.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

Download a Pre build package from [Spark Downloads](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), in the archive you'll find the examples, the binaries are in the `lib` folder: `spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar`, and sources in the `examples` folder.

Comment: I am looking for maven provided pre-builts. Are there any?